# Activity only included in specific build variants

Tags: android

Suppose I have the following build variants: `debug`, `qa`, and `release`. Is it possible to have an Activity in the source sets for `debug` and `qa`, but isn't included in `release`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. First, move YourActivity.java from `src/main/` to `src/debug/` AND `src/qa/`. Be sure to keep the same directory structure that the Activity had in `src/main/`.

You will also remove the Activity tag from the `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. Then use Android Studio's manifest merger to add the Activity tag to the original manifest by using the below code in the new files `src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` and `src/qa/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.example">

    <application
        android:name="MyApplication">
        <activity android:name=".fq_domain.YourActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Lastly, obfuscate all calls to that Activity like so:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName("com.example.example.fq_domain.YourActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is in case of the `release` build, which shouldn't crash because it doesn't define the Activity in the manifest.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it's possible. You can create temporary activity and check build variants.

In MainActivity:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  startActivity(DebugAcivity)
} else if (BuildConfig.QA) {
  startActivity(QaActivity)
} else if (...) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This does not remove the source files from the apk build.